# Java OpenCV: Specified feature detector type is not supported

Tags: java, opencv, opencv3.0

I downloaded the `OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1`. I am experiment it in Java.

I try to use the `SURF feature detector`:

```
FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
```

But it reports the error below:

[image]

Why? Is the Java wrapper of OpenCV is not complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the Java wrapper for `OpenCV 3.0.0-rc1` is indeed incomplete. I turned to use the `2.4.10`, the `SURF` detector and many others are available now.

Just as @berak commented, the extra modules need to be added to the main repo by yourself.